# Geany, Linux, C#, MySql.Data, NOT Visual Studio; the using statement doesn't compile

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, mono, geany

I just got C# working on Ubutnu. It's all good. But now I want MySql too. I installed the gacutil, and downloaded the connector, and I ran the gacutil, which it seemed like it worked.

I'm using Geany as my ide for now. It's free and already installed, and it worked great; until I tried to add using MySql.Data; I've read through all the stackoverflow posts for MySql.Data: they all state that I need to add an entry to my reference list in the VS project. Well, I don't have a reference list, nor a project. My 'project' directory only contains two(2) files: Test.cs, and Test.exe. MySql.Data is registered in the gac! Arg! Please, how do I get this working?!?!?

Running the gacutil:

> dysmondad@Julep:/etc/mono/mysql/v4.5$ sudo gacutil -i MySql.Data.dll
>    Installed MySql.Data.dll into the gac (/usr/lib/mono/gac)

Complete source code for testing Mono install.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MySql.Data; // <- this isn't recognized.

public class Test
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        List<int> integers = new List<int>();
        integers.Add(7);
        integers.Add(14);
        integers.Add(21);
        foreach( int i in integers )
        {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE-1: Just found this on the MySql support page.
_______
You are now ready to compile your application. You must ensure that when you compile your application you include the Connector/Net component using the -r: command-line option. For example:
shell> gmcs -r:System.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:MySql.Data.dll HelloWorld.cs
But...these don't work

> -r:MySql.Data.dll

--nor--

> -r:MySql.Data

UPDATE-2: I just discovered that if I use the -r option, and include the full path and name of the dll (even though it was registered with the gacutil) that seems to satisfy the compiler. So now my question is: how to get it to work with just the package name and not have to specify the full path?

Comment: Maybe just use proper .net ide, like MonoDevelop?

Comment: @Evk, I just tried that. It seems that the MonoDevelop package installs via  something called flatpak. It turned out to be problematic. There is a (depreciated) repository method to install it. I'll give that a try.